# how to translate this code to xml

Tags: android, textview

I have an example of adding a textview programmatically what I wanted to do is to add the same textview in xml so that I can position it in a specific location in the layout is there a way to turn this code to xml?

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like the following

```
//activity_mylayout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_textview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="40sp" />

//MyActivity.java
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mylayout); // Sets the xml layout as the view
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_textview); // Gets a reference to a component using the id
myTextView.setText(message);
```

Comment: Yep, don't forget the + it tells Android to create the id (there are ways to create a predefined list of ids, but this is the preferred method)

Comment: can you show me here another way of defining id if its not too much for you.and how it differ for the custom way of defining I only define id like this android:id="@+id/'idname'"

Comment: It's just like your external strings are defined. Not worth it for most projects.